# How to detect an instance of an anonymous class?

Tags: php, instance, anonymous-class

Since PHP7, we have [anonymous classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php#language.oop5.anonymous).

How can we know if an `$instance` is an instance of an anonymous class?

Comment: Out of interest, what are you using Anonymous Classes for? They're pretty interesting, and cool; but (outside of a few specialist libraries) I've not seen any use-cases where they're particularly useful

Comment: @MarkBaker I need to create an object in a callback quickly and it must implement a certain interface ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using [Reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.isanonymous.php)

```
$instance = new class {};

$testInstance = new ReflectionClass($instance);
var_dump($testInstance->isAnonymous());
```

**EDIT**

Of course, given that you must be running PHP7 for anonymous classes anyway, wrap it up into a one-liner

```
var_dump((new ReflectionClass($instance))->isAnonymous());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one: [Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.isanonymous.php)

```
<?php 
class TestClass {}
$anonClass = new class {};

$normalClass = new ReflectionClass('TestClass');
$anonClass  = new ReflectionClass($anonClass);

var_dump($normalClass->isAnonymous());
var_dump($anonClass->isAnonymous());
?>
```

Output:

> bool(false)
>   bool(true)